# Line generalization not working

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, generalization

After having installed the plugin - [Cartographic Line Generalization](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/CartoLineGen-master/) - I try to open the tool in the Plugins menu and receive the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'wkbSize' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alexander/.qgis2/python/plugins/CartoLineGen-master/cartolinegen.py", line 245, in count_vertices
    count = sum([feature.geometry().wkbSize() for feature in feat])/16
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'wkbSize'
```

There is one geojson line layer in the layer table when this happens - what could be the issue ?

Comment: I suspect you have some null / empty / invalid geometries. QGIS might load this geojson file, but plugins can be less forgiving...